# How to add special character in array map?

Tags: javascript, array-map

How to add special characters like `:` to array map ? I want to achieve this.

```
'10': ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"]
```

this is what I have so far

```js
const data = [{
  "user_id": "10",
  "dates": ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"]
}]

const output = data.map(({
  user_id,
  dates
}) => [user_id, dates]);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: `'10': ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"]` isn’t a value. Get familiar with [how to access and process objects, arrays, or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212), how to [access properties](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), and how to create [objects](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) or [arrays](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array#array_literal_notation).

Comment: Do you mean you want to create an object like `{"10": ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"]}`? (The quotes around the `10` there are optional, but I thought it was clearer to write them in this case.) If so, you can't do that with `map`, `map` produces an **array**. Or did you perhaps want an array of objects like that? If so, it would make sense to show a starting point with more than one object, and it's a matter of just creating the destination object from the source object in the `map` callback.

Comment: [{"user_id":"10","dates":["11/21/2022","11/25/2022"]}] = this is the original output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you're looking for an array like this as your result:

```
[
    {
        10: ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"]
    },
    // ...possibly others here...
]
```

If so, return a non-array object from your `map` call rather than an array:

```
const output = data.map(({ user_id, dates }) => ({[user_id]: dates}));
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Example:

```js
const data = [
    {
        user_id: "10",
        dates: ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"],
    },
];

const output = data.map(({ user_id, dates }) => ({[user_id]: dates}));
console.log(output);
```

Note how that uses [computed property name syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) to create the property in the object, `[user_id]: dates`. That creates a property using the *value* of `user_id` as the name.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to console.log to appear in the way you described, this then you just have to access the elements from the array and print them in the way you want.

```js
const data = [{
  "user_id": "10",
  "dates": ["11/21/2022", "11/25/2022"]
}]

const output = data.map(({
  user_id,
  dates
}) => [user_id, dates]);
console.log(`'${output[0][0]}': ["${output[0][1][0]}, ${output[0][1][1]}"]`);
```

Comment: what if the dates are dynamic or it can have more than two?